# How to find the total sum of dynamic row in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops, calculation

I am using `JavaScript` to show text box dynamically

[image]

and calculations are used in `javascript` like

```
function add_number(k) {
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate-"+k).value);
    var units = parseFloat(document.getElementById("unit-"+k).value);
    var disc = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dis-"+k).value);
    var result = rate * units;
    var discnt =result - disc;
    var disamt =parseFloat(discnt).toFixed(2);
    var utgp = 9;
    var persnt = parseFloat((discnt * utgp) /100).toFixed(2);
    var totl = discnt +(persnt * 2);
    var totls = parseFloat(totl).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("taxs-"+k).value = disamt;
    document.getElementById("utgp-"+k).value = utgp;
    document.getElementById("utg-"+k).value = persnt;
    document.getElementById("cgstp-"+k).value = utgp;
    document.getElementById("cgst-"+k).value = persnt;
    document.getElementById("total-"+k).value = totls;
    document.getElementById("taxtotal").value = disamt;
}
```

how to find tax total here show last enter value I have to show every click of tax amt field show total in below column how to calculate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#This may Help you out#
var total=0;
function add_number(k) {
var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate-"+k).value);
var units =parseFloat(document.getElementById("unit-"+k).value);
var disc = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dis-"+k).value);
var result = rate * units;
var discnt =result - disc;
var disamt =parseFloat(discnt).toFixed(2);
var utgp = 9;
var persnt = parseFloat((discnt * utgp) /100).toFixed(2);
var totl = discnt +(persnt * 2);
var totls = parseFloat(totl).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("taxs-"+k).value = disamt;
document.getElementById("utgp-"+k).value = utgp;
document.getElementById("utg-"+k).value = persnt;
document.getElementById("cgstp-"+k).value = utgp;
document.getElementById("cgst-"+k).value = persnt;
document.getElementById("total-"+k).value = totls;
document.getElementById("taxtotal").value = disamt;
total = parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(totls);
alert(total);
}
```

Comment: and concatenate 1+1=11 why ? i will the add two numbers are !NaN ,so why the answer show this type.......

Comment: 1] Please add **"parseFloat"** while adding. 2] **document.getElementById("taxs-"+k).value = disamt;** change all these into **disamt = document.getElementById("taxs-"+k).value**;